# Django ModelFormset error empty form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Django has decided to throw an error when I am submitting the form.  The form is a modelformset and I have made absolutely no change to the default, merely clicking on submitting button.  Django complains that the only empty form needs to have a value and when I change it to required = False:

```
forms.CharField(max_length = 40, required = False)
```

it stops complaining. Here is my form:

```
class RateForm(ModelForm):
    costcode =  forms.CharField(max_length = 40, required = False)
    class Meta:
        model = Rate
        fields = ['costcode', 'rate', 'UOM', ]

class BaseRateFormSet(BaseModelFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        ''' No custom cleaning at this point.'''
        cd = super(BaseRateFormSet, self).clean()
```

To see what is going on, I wrote the custom cleaning and saw that the cd is None when I added assert False after it.

the view:

```
rate_formset = RateFormSet(request.POST if any(request.POST) else None, 
                                            prefix = user.short_name, 
                                            form_kwargs = the_form_kwargs, 
                                            **user_form_kwargs)
```

In reality, the field costcode should be required, but Django should realize that the user does not wish to submit any additional form, so it does not generate the error.  How do I get Django to not throw an error on an empty form?

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and except ...

```
Try: 
     rate_formset = RateFormSet(request.POST if any(request.POST) else None, 
                                            prefix = user.short_name, 
                                            form_kwargs = the_form_kwargs, 
                                            **user_form_kwargs)
Except:
     ....
```

(Show all of your views and I can help more ...)

Comment: The question is why does it require an empty form in a formset to have non-empty field?

Comment: Because it's not 'empty'; it's 'not required'. An empty entity would be "Null=True", not "Required=False" ...Try removing null=false from your model field, which I am assuming is there ...